# uitableview prototype cells scrolling issue after updating xcode 8

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, xcode8

I have upgraded Xcode from version 7.4 to 8.0.

**Before upgrading**

I was working on a project in Xcode 7.4 and had uitableview with prototype cells in storyboard. I used to scroll prototype cells and every thing was working fine, I could scroll and select buttons and labels that I click on.

**After upgrading**

When I first open storyboard and goto same tableview that has prototype cells, I can select buttons and labels as expected. example is here

[image]

But, When I scroll down/up then the selection rectangle stays and does not move with other views, while other objects move correctly. see the screenshot beloe:

[image]

After this I cannot even select any textfield, label or button etc.

Anyone having same issue?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I am still looking for answer, can someone help me?

Comment: try to remove constraint and check again. @Muhammad Irfan

Comment: I am not using auto layout

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs when you using xib or storyboard in xcode8 and xcode 8.1 than 7.X.